# Ruby on rails cannot fill form unless true

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms, email, view, radio-button

I want to implement something that has. do you want to send an email to users? have a yes or no radio button. And only if the radio button says yes. Should the text below it allow the person to fill in the email content to send out. This is what I have for email content but I do not know how to make it dependent on the buttons.

```
 <div align="center">
  Open orders?
  &nbsp;&nbsp;
  Yes
  <%= f.radio_button :orders_open, true, :class=>"radio-control"%> 
  &nbsp;&nbsp;
  No
  <%= f.radio_button :orders_open, false, :class=>"radio-control"%> 

</div>

<br>

 <div align="center">

  Email users?
  &nbsp;&nbsp;
  Yes
  <%= f.radio_button :email_users, true, :class=>"radio-control"%> 
  &nbsp;&nbsp;
  No
  <%= f.radio_button :email_users, false, :class=>"radio-control", :checked => true %> 

</div>
<br> <br>
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label">
    <%= f.label :email_content, "Note to users" %>
  </label>
  <% if @application_state.orders_open %>
    <div class="controls">
        <%= f.text_area :email_content %>
    </div>
  <% else %>
    <div class="controls">
        <%= f.text_area :email_content %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @Newcastle, this question is very hard to understand.  The question part has partial sentences and no formatting.  The code part seems to be a fragment of some file.  I think you'll find you get much better responses if you work on phrasing and formatting.  You can click the `edit` link to update the question.

Answer (score 1):

Using JavaScript you can do, that you want easily.
Bind event on selection change of radio button, and on the basis of required condition enable or disable email_content text-area.

```
<input type="radio" id="no" name="email_users"/>
<input type="radio" id="yes" name="email_users"/>
<textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="email_content">
</textarea>
```

Solve the problem using jQuery:

```
jQuery("input[name=email_users]").change(function (e) {
  if(this.id === "yes") {
    jQuery("#email_content").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  }
  else if(this.id === "no"){
    jQuery("#email_content").removeAttr('disabled');;
  }
}
```